# How to add javadoc with usage of gradle wrapper

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm using code from book Pro Spring 5 https://github.com/Apress/pro-spring-5 which is multimodule project and even though I added

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

to many build.gradle files also to the one with the highest hierarchy but I don't see any javadoc, for example when I want to see javadoc to annotation @SpringBootApplication, type ctrl+q and I don't see documentation but

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure @Target({ElementType.TYPE}) 

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
    @Documented 
    @Inherited 
    @SpringBootConfiguration 
    @EnableAutoConfiguration 
    @ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {@org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter(type = org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = {org.springframework.boot.context.TypeExcludeFilter.class}),@org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter(type = org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class})}) 
    public interface SpringBootApplication
    extends annotation.Annotation

      Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.0.6.RELEASE
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I rectified my question